# Não consigo alterar o valor de variaveis locais na Unity

Tags: c#, funções, unity3d, timer, corotina

Olá, estou tentando desenvolver um timer na Unity usando coroutine, segue o código:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Threading;

public class timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine("updateTimer");
    }

    IEnumerator updateTimer () {
        int seconds = 59;
        int minutes = 1;
        do
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            seconds = seconds - 1;
            if (minutes > 0 && seconds == 0)
                minutes = minutes - 1; seconds = 59;
            if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
                timeOut();
            print(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            string text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
            gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text = text;
        } while (seconds != 0 && minutes != 0);
    }

    void timeOut()
    {
        player.GetComponent<Die>().killExpress();
    }
}
```

Na função `updateTimer` crio duas variaveis uma de minutos e outra de segundos, o código dentro do `do` não altera o valor dos minutos nem dos segundos por algum motivo, e o unico valor retornado é o valor de origem. Queria sabe por que isso acontece e como resolver.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: olá, uma pergunta, você sabe o que esse código faz e o que é esperado? tem vários problemas ai, mas o foco é, seu iterator tem um return logo no início, como espera que ele continue o código para mudar o valor das variáveis se já fez return? pra além disso, uma variável public (player) não é uma boa ideia, ela deveria ser private ou transformada numa propriedade, nome da classe "camelCase", deveria ser "PascalCase" e de preferência um nome que já não exista no framework (já existe uma classe Timer), if sem `{ }` não vai nem executar os dois comandos, se é que isso era esperado, etc etc etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem? Então, ao que parece você quer 1 timer que a partir de 2 segundos ele ative a sua função timeOut(), correto? A forma ideal de você fazer um timer no Unity é utilizando o Time.deltaTime e tente utilizar também apenas segundos!

Por exemplo, no seu caso de precisar aguardar 2 minutos, você teria apenas 1 variável seconds com o valor de 120 (pois 60 segundos = 1 minuto, logo 60x2=120) do tipo float (pois o Time.deltaTime é do tipo float também).

E para aguardar 2 minutos você precisaria apenas decrementar da sua variável seconds do Time.deltaTime. Você pode fazer de 2 formas utilizando corrotinas:

1. Nessa primeira forma você **nem precisa do Time.deltaTime**, o **WaitForSeconds** da corrotina já irá aguardar os 2 minutos que você precisa para realizar a ação do timeOut();

```
IEnumerator updateTimer ()
{
        float seconds = 120f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);  
        timeOut();
}
```

2. A segunda é utilizando o Time.deltaTime para decrementar da variável seconds, dessa forma você poderá ter acesso ao valor da variável em tempo real para caso queira mostrar ela em algum component tipo Text:

```
IEnumerator updateTimer ()
{
        float seconds = 120f;
        while(seconds > 0)
        {
          int minutesText = (int) (seconds/60f);
          int secondsText = (int) (((seconds/60f) - minutesText)*60f)
          print(minutesText + ":" + secondsText);
          string text = minutesText + ":" + secondsText;
          gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text = text;
          yield return null;
          seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        }  
        timeOut();
}
```